# Swift cant use hidesBarsOnSwipe because of embedded table view

Tags: ios, swift

In my VC I have a container view that holds an embedded table view.

My problem now is that I cant use `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`

In my VC since it won't pick up swipes from the embedded table view. I have also tried to set hidesBarsOnSwipe = true in my table views VC but I can't catch that in VC1.

I have also tried to make deletages in my table view that fires once I scroll up or down and then I hide the navigation bar. But the problem there is that I can't get it to stay hidden or visible since the scroll has a bounce effect / pull to refresh = will hide/show my nav bar a few times in a row since its bouncing. And I don't want to remove the bounce effect.

So is there any way to detect `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` in an embedded table view?

Comment: Have you find the solution? If yes, then please share.

Comment: pointer to related, but not the same question, just in case ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675608/hidesbarsonswipe-never-shows-navbar-again-when-scrolling-up

Answer (score 0):

You can add a gesture recognizer, and in its delegate return true in method called `func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` to make tableView work alongside with GestureRecognizer. After that you can handle swipes to hide or show navigationBar whenever you wan.