# Table view in UIViewController doesn't get hidesBarsOnSwipe functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a table view as the first child of a regular UIViewController. I've tried adding the navigation controller's `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer` gesture recognizer to both my view and table view, but no dice. In the snippet below, blah: is never getting called.

```
[self.navigationController setHidesBarsOnSwipe:YES];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer];
[self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(blah:)];
```

I feel like the `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer` is the way to tap into this nice functionality when not using a top level scroll view controller (collection or table), but I can't figure out exactly how.

Comment: do you want to hide your navigation bar when you scroll your tableview ? Right ?

Comment: yes, exactly @Lion - the problem was that unless the table view was pinned precisely to the dimensions of the top level view, it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide `navigationbar` on swipe, meaning when you scroll your `tableview` in upward direction (goes to down) then

```
 self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

is enough to achieve this. It will hide the `navigationbar` and show it again on `tap`. Make sure you have set proper constraint to `tableview`. your constraint should be `top,bottom,leading and trailing` with constant of `0` with `nearest neighbor`.

Comment: That sounds crazy, but it works. I had a view above my tableview so the constraints weren't directly to the top and bottom layout guides. Unfortunately, while it hides, it still doesn't reappear. I'm going to dig some more but thanks for the help

Comment: This answer fixed the never-reappearing part of the hiding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28899115/822164

Comment: Yeah as i have said it's depends on your constraints!